# Expansion of HypergeometricU

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I try to get the first three terms of expansion of `HypergeometricU` in Mathematica.

My input is `Normal[Series[HypergeometricU[B-A,B,-P*t],{t,0,3} ] ]`

The output is

```
Gamma[1-B]/Gamma[1-A]+((A-B) P t Gamma[1-B])/(B Gamma[1-A])+((-A+B) (1-A+B) P^2 t^2 Gamma[1-B])/(2 B (1+B) Gamma[1-A])-((-A+B) (1-A+B) (2-A+B) P^3 t^3 Gamma[1-B])/(6 B (1+B) (2+B) Gamma[1-A])+E^(2 I (1-B) \[Pi] Floor[(\[Pi]-Arg[-P]-Arg[t])/(2 \[Pi])]) t^-B (((-P)^(1-B) t Gamma[-1+B])/Gamma[-A+B]+((-1+A) (-P)^-B P^2 t^2 Gamma[-1+B])/((-2+B) Gamma[-A+B])-((-2+A) (-1+A) (-P)^-B P^3 t^3 Gamma[-1+B])/(2 (-3+B) (-2+B) Gamma[-A+B]))
```

I am not sure how the $e^{2 i (1-B)}$ term appears. It is not in the usual [expansion of HypergeometricU](http://functions.wolfram.com/PDF/HypergeometricU.pdf).

Can you please help me figure out why this happens and how to fix this to get the usual expansion.

Comment: Try to apply this: `% // FullSimplify[#, t >= 0] &` to the result. In my case after that, this strange term disappeared.

Comment: Yeah. it does disappear! Thank you. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I think, it is just since normally MMa simplifies each result by itself by the operation like `Simplify`. However, for special functions, it is not always the case since `Simplify`does not always work far enough on the special functions. Therefore, we need to sometimes force it to simplify further by using `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Since `Series` accepts the option `Assumptions` use `Normal[Series[HypergeometricU[B - A, B, -P*t], {t, 0, 3}, 
  Assumptions -> t >= 0]]`